# On the behaviour of $\sum\binom{n}{k} (a-1)^k$ where the sum is on $k\le n(1-1/a)$, for some $a>1$

Tags: limits, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I just came up with the following limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\displaystyle\log_a\Bigg(\sum_{\substack{k\in \mathbb{N}\\k\leq n~(1-\frac{1}{a})}}\binom{n}{k} (a-1)^k\Bigg)}{n}
\qquad \text{ where } (a>1).$$
I am not able to solve it? Any hints?

**Update:** By Greg Martin comment, the limit hopefully will be $1$: A complete proof will be appreciated.

Comment: Since the complete sum is $a^n$, the quotient is at most $1$; presumably the limit does equal $1$, and note that even bounding the given truncated sum below by $a^n/n^K$ would establish this. (I'm guessing the true value is actually aymptotic to $a^nC(a)$ for some constant $C(a)$.) Note that the given sum is the Taylor polynomial of degree $\lfloor n(1-\frac1a)\rfloor$, to $f(x)=x^n$ at $x=1$, evaluated at $x=a$; perhaps Taylor's remainder theorem gives an adequate bound?

Comment: @GregMartin thanks for your reply. As you said, "presumably the limit does equal 1". I am trying to show this now, but still there is no complete proof. Bests

Comment: The sum in the logarithm is $$a^nP(S_n\leqslant E(S_n))$$ where $S_n$ is binomial $(n,1-\frac1a)$. By the most standard version of the central limit theorem, $$P(S_n\leqslant E(S_n))\to\frac12$$ hence the ratio in the question is $$1-\frac{\log_a2}n+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$ and in particular the desired limit is $$1$$

Answer (score 0):

Remark that $$1+S(n)=1+\sum_{\substack{k\in \mathbb{N}\\k\leq n~(1-\frac{1}{a})}}\binom{n}{k} (a-1)^k =\frac{F(n\left(1-\frac 1a\right);n,\frac{a-1}a)}{a^n},$$

where $F(l; n,p)$ is the probability that are at most $l$ successes in  the [binomial distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n$ and $p$. Thus is, we put $l= n\left(1-\frac 1a\right)$ and $p=\frac{a-1}a$. By one version of Laplace theorem (from an article of vol.4 of Russian “Mathematical Encyclopedia”, Moskow, Soviet Encyclopedia, 1982)

$$F(l; n,p)=\Phi\left(\frac{l+1.5-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right)+O\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\right),$$

where $$\Phi(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2}dt.$$

Thus $$1+S(n)=a^n\left(\Phi\left(\frac{1.5a}{\sqrt{n(a-1)}}\right)+O\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right),$$

$$\log_a S(n)=n+O(1),$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log_a\frac{S(n)}n=1.$$